# Session expired before timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net

I set sessiontimeout in web.config file like following.

```
<sessionState timeout="120"
         cookieless="false"
          mode="InProc"
        />
```

Some times above code working fine.But many times session expired after 10 to 15 minutes automatically.

and this errors exists in every browser.

when i run same application using .net on my local computer it working fine.

**Please note that, i haven't create global.ascx file yet.**

Comment: global.ascx is not affact to this reason ..its just for handle event. it would not happen but still you can try to change session time in IIS. actually first pref is Web.config if not set in config file then it will use IIS.

Comment: Are you talking about the production server? What web server application are you using? IIS?

Answer (score 6):

Sessions will also be reset when the application recycles. This will happen when you change some things in the site, like change anything in the "bin" folder or modify the "web.config" file.

Also IIS may stop or recycle applications that it thinks are not used at the moment.

Are you sure you want to keep everything in memory for two hours, even after the user left? Better ways to keep the session alive would be to use some regular (every few minutes) AJAX callback. Search for "session keep alive asp.net ajax".

Comment: Thanks for reply, but session expired when user is acive in website

Comment: @UdaySatardekar - Do you mean "requesting pages" or "busy filling in one form"? IIS and ASP.Net only count request and can't see that a user still has a page in his/her browser. A "keep alive" will help in telling IIS/ASP.Net that the user is still busy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified the session timeout the app is ending up with? Do a response.write of Session.Timeout. This value can be set in several places.

How do you know the user is being active? The session will time out if he's only typing text, scrolling, and/or reading for lengths of time greater than the timeout value. The browser must invoke a HTTP request to the server to reset the timer.

As Hans mentioned, a background script-based "pinger" set to run at interval to access minimal web content will help.

Considering I'm about to start yet another web application, and I seem to need to add this functionality to most web apps, I was inspired to create a little package called *Keep Me Alive* to speed this process up in the future.  You can find it here:
http://kma.codeplex.com/

Hope it helps!